# pulling data from XML CLOB field

Tags: xml, oracle-sqldeveloper, clob

I need help formatting Oracle SQL to extract data from a XML CLOB field that has format different than the examples I have googled.  I have been getting different error messages when trying a XMLTABLE format, so perhaps the PATH to find the values or other portions syntax are incorrect.

How do I call the appropriate field in these DynFormDataItem  FieldName and FieldValue sets of data in the CLOB field?

I changed table and variable names from what I have to make source information generic.

Example Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT
SalesPerson.SalesPersonID,
SalesPerson.StartDate,
SalesData.SalesPersonID,
ExtractedSalesData.SALESPERSON,
ExtractedSalesData.CASH

FROM
SalesPerson
INNER JOIN SalesData on SalesData.SalesPersonID = SalesPerson.SalesPersonID
,XMLTABLE(‘/MYHIDDENSERVERNAME’
   PASSING XMLTYPE(‘SalesData.FORM_XML_CLOB_TEXT’)

   COLUMNS SALESPERSON VARCHAR2(50) PATH ‘Sales Person’

   COLUMNS CASH VARCHAR2(30) PATH ‘Cash’

) AS ExtractedSalesData

;
```

Error Message:

```
ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation:

XVM-01003: [XPST0003] Syntax error at 'Person'

1   Sales Person

-          ^

19112. 00000 -  "error raised during evaluation: %s"

*Cause:    The error function was called during evaluation of the XQuery expression.

*Action:   Check the detailed error message for the possible causes.

Error at Line: (gives me line where XMLTABLE starts)
```

Tables/fields:

```
SalesPerson.SalesPersonID
SalesPerson.StartDate

SalesData.SalesPersonID
SalesData.FORM_XML_CLOB_TEXT

Example of the field FORM_XML_CLOB_TEXT:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ArrayOfDynFormDataItem xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<DynFormDataItem>
<FieldName>The Form Description</FieldName>
<FieldValue>This form is used to track sales activity.</FieldValue>
</DynFormDataItem>

<DynFormDataItem>
<FieldName>Sales Person</FieldName>
<FieldValue>John Smith</FieldValue>
</DynFormDataItem>

<DynFormDataItem>
<FieldName>Cash</FieldName>
<FieldValue>850.00</FieldValue>
</DynFormDataItem>

</ArrayOfDynFormDataItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have backticks instead of quotes, and various other syntax errors like two `COLUMN` keywords, and you are looking for a node called `'/MYHIDDENSERVERNAME` which doesn't exist in your XML. (Curiously it doesn't mind `AS` in the XMLTable alias in this context.)

But ignoring all that, the error - as the message says - is that you are looking for a path of `'Sales person', which is the value of a node, not the name of a node.

You need to find the FieldValue corresponding to the FieldName with value 'SalesPerson', so you can do:

```
SELECT
  SalesPerson.SalesPersonID,
  SalesPerson.StartDate,
  SalesData.SalesPersonID,
  ExtractedSalesData.SALESPERSON,
  ExtractedSalesData.CASH
FROM
  SalesPerson
INNER JOIN
  SalesData
ON
  SalesData.SalesPersonID = SalesPerson.SalesPersonID
CROSS JOIN
  XMLTABLE(
    '/ArrayOfDynFormDataItem'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(SalesData.FORM_XML_CLOB_TEXT)
    COLUMNS
      SALESPERSON VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'DynFormDataItem[FieldName="Sales Person"]/FieldValue',
      CASH VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'DynFormDataItem[FieldName="Cash"]/FieldValue'
) ExtractedSalesData;
```

| SALESPERSONID | STARTDATE | SALESPERSONID | SALESPERSON | CASH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 23-AUG-22 | 42 | John Smith | 850.00 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=18af9a86795979e984ca522284d34657)

The path `DynFormDataItem[FieldName="Sales Person"]` finds the `DynFormData` node which has a child `FieldName` node with value 'Sales Person'; and then `/FieldValue` gives you the corresponding value of that node under that specific `DynFormData` node.